# MySQL Table Locks

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-normalization, database-deadlocks

I was asked to do some PHP scripts on MySQL DB to show some data when I noticed the strange design they had.
They want to perform a study that would require collecting up to 2000 records per user and they are automatically creating a new table for each user that registers. It's a pilot study at this stage so they have around 30 tables but they should have 3000 users for the real study.

I wanted to suggest gathering all of them in a single table but since there might be around 1500 INSERTs per minute to that database during the study period, I wanted to ask this question here first. Will that cause table locks in MySQL?
So, Is it one table with 1500 INSERTs per minute and a maximum size of 6,000,000 records or 3000 tables with 30 INSERTs per minute and a maximum size of 2000 records. I would like to suggest the first option but I want to be sure that it will not cause any issues.
I read that InnoDB has row-level locks. So, will that have a better performance combined with the one table option?

Comment: Flip the question and ask, "why would anyone create multiple tables to store the same data?".  Obviously the disk IO, indexing, etc., will be the same.  I would guess that either they thought it was the only way to get around table locking in myisam, or they really had no clue what they were doing.  Flip it to innodb and don't look back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge loaded question.  In my experience performance is not really measured accurately by table size alone.  It comes down to design.  Do you have the primary keys and indexes in place?  Is it over indexed?  That being said, I have also found that almost always one trip to the DB is faster than dozens.  How big is the single table (columns)?  What kind of data are you saving (larger than 4000K?).  It might be that you need to create some prototypes to see what performs best for you.  The most I can recommend is that you carefully judge the size of the data you are collecting and allocate accordingly, create indexes (but not too many, don't over index), and test.

Comment: Each table has 4 columns and each row should have no more than 400 bytes that is a mix between text fields and datetime. Given that they have 48 GB of RAM and 2 x 6-core Xeon CPU and 6 HDs in RAID10 config, I think that one table with 6 Million records would perform well. Right? I can also ask them to limit their INSERTs to one operation a minute with 30 records because that is the maximum that can be generated by a user per minute (collecting inserted words). Will that help?

Comment: Doing one larger operation will be "better" than doing 30 smaller ones.  That said, I hate making product people change things on their end due to tech issues; I'd rather solve the tech issue when possible/feasible.  Sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: Thanks. I discussed re-designing their DB and data collection with them and they will do it.